# query windows for number of timers created

Tags: c++, windows

I know there is a maximum amount of timers that windows can run (~10000). Is there a way to see in C++ how many timers are currently running/allocated? I haven't found anything in the docs about it yet.

Comment: `GetGuiResources(hProcess, GR_USEROBJECTS);` I think - not an answer as I'm not 100% sure but should be easy to check. Also see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090827-00/?p=16963

Comment: Unfortunately, we have a fair number of non-timer GUI objects in the process (or at least I'm sure I don't have 1600 timers!).

Comment: Yeah that's all (User) objects. But that's the value which is compared t the max, so if you care about running out you only really care about that value. Or if you think you're leaking then again that value running out of control will tell you something is leaking (which is well worth knowing). But finding out the exact number of _only_ timers I couldn't find.